# Changing the journal logo on elsarticle template

Tags: elsarticle, logos

I downloaded the elsarticle template from the Pattern Recognition journal latex site and I've been trying to change the logo to no avail.

I know the template uses the format <\jid>logo.pdf where it will search for proenglogo.pdf if \jid{proeng} but every time I run this, I get the journal logo being the dummy logo. I also cannot use the dummy journal logo as it goes over the lines of the logo boundaries (see picture below).

I used TexStudio after using Overleaf and still nothing ...

Code:
\jid{proeng}

File in the same directory as the tex file:
proenglogo.pdf

Maybe I need to put it into its own folder?

Any help would be appreciated! [image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the logo named `PRlogo.jpg` in your working directory, you can insert it using

```
\renewcommand{\jnllogo}{\includegraphics[height=60pt,keepaspectratio]{PRlogo}}
```

[image: a]

```
\documentclass[3p,times]{elsarticle}

\usepackage{ecrc}
\volume{00}

\firstpage{1}

\journal{Pattern Recognition}

\runauth{Me et al.}

\renewcommand{\jnllogo}{\includegraphics[height=60pt,keepaspectratio]{PRlogo}}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % Only dummy text

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frontmatter}
            
        \title{A nice title }
        
        \author{author1}
        \author{author2}    
        \address{address1}
        \address{address2}
        
        \begin{abstract}
            \kant[1]
        \end{abstract}
        
        \begin{keyword}
            key1,key2,key3
        \end{keyword}
        
    \end{frontmatter}
    
    \section{Introduction}  
    \kant[2-8]  
    
\end{document
```

Used the files included in [files to run this package](https://www.elsevier.com/__data/assets/file/0004/56938/elsarticle-ecrc.zip)

Comment: Thanks! Now it works